# does “ubuntu update(via auto software updater)” change the release number of ubuntu which I am using?

Tags: update-manager

I am new with ubuntu. Does the auto software updater updates the version I am using or it upgrades to a new release?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Automatic software updates won't upgrade your release to a newer version, you get a separate prompt for that.